# Pentaho: Table Output taking more time to insert records

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

We want to copy table data from one database to another. The table
has 3M records. I have used Table Output step. I have set all required
parameters. But still it is taking a long time.

```
"rewriteBatchedStatements" = "true"
"net_write_timeout" = "12000"
"zeroDateTimeBehavior" = "convertToNull"
"useServerPrepStmts" = "false"
"useCursorFetch" = "true"
"useCompression" = "true"
```

Commit size is 500. I tried increasing it up to 10000 as well.

Is there any way to tune this? Or any other step that I can use? Because in
SQLyog tool, to copy a table's data from one database to another database doesn't take much time. It takes hardly one min.

Comment: What is the target DB (Oracle, PostgreSQL, ...)? Have you tried bulk loading the data with the tool's own loader? 1 min is usually what I get for 3M rows, so something is likely wrong indeed.

Comment: Target DB is MySQL. I tried loading with MySQL's own loader. But I want to load through Pentaho as Pentaho's main purpose is for faster loading. so, can we do fast loading in Pentaho itself?

Comment: But what happens when you bulk load? If it's fast, it suggests something's wrong with your PDI install/transform. If not, something's wrong with the database.